# how to use result of for loop in further iterations of for loop C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, recursion, iteration

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    float I_0 = log(11 / 10);
    float I_n;
        for (n=1; n <= 20; n++) { 
            I_n = (1.0 / n) - 10.0 * I_0;
            std::cout << "the value of I_" << n << " is " << I_n << 
std::endl;
            I_0 = I_n;
        return I_0;

    }       
}
```

what i am trying to do is use the value generated by the for loop, I_n, and then use it again in the next iteration as the I_0 - each iteration informs the next. But this code Ive written isnt working - this just return I_1=1, which is for sure wrong in terms of the value - but also, where are the other 19 iterations?

So my question is: I have this initial value of I_0=ln(11/10). This informs the value of I_1, and then I use I_1 to find the value of I_2 etc...is my program kind of right for this? or what should i try instead? Ive tried writing the changing I_0 as a pointer function, which was an if-else loop, along the lines of

```
if(n=1){
I_n_1=I_0
}
else
{
I_n_1=I_n}
```

where the I_n_1 is the term before the I_n, but its not included in my current code, because it didnt work, because oyu cant have functions as if else loops. Ive also considered the fact that this seems recursive, and how to write this in c++ is beyond me so far, so any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: `11/10` is 1. Change it to `11.0/10.0`.

Comment: @PeteBecker doh...yes of course..that was dumb. that gives the right result, but the for loop still terminates after n=1 - any idea why?

Comment: `return` will end the function you are in, in this case `main` and thus terminate your program.

Comment: @super oh yes, i just tried it and it works! sorry for the dumb question, but i was taught that you always needed a return function, but i probably misunderstood the context. you dont always need a return function then?

Comment: You `return` a value from a function, if you want. It's not mandatory. A `void` function will not return any value.  `int main` is declared to return an `int`, so it should always return a value. If you don't have any relevant information to return, just put a `return 0;` at the end of `main`.

Comment: You might want to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you step through your program in a debugger then the problem should have become obvious very quickly.